# Using macro to fill header with data from cell

Tags: excel, vba

We have m-files and use the properties system to display document properties in excel documents. But we want some of properties to be displayed in excel "header".
So I created a button that updates properties of header whenever it is pressed.

But i have a problem now because i want to fill all 3 headers(LeftHeader, CenterHeader, RightHeader) with properties, but my macro only fills CenterHeader and I have no idea why..
Here is my Macro:

`Sub AddHeaderToAll_FromMETADATASheet()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws.PageSetup
            .LeftHeader = ""
            .CenterHeader = ""
            .RightHeader = ""
            .LeftHeader = "&6" & Worksheets("METADATA").Range("B24").Value
            .RightHeader = "&6" & Worksheets("METADATA").Range("B25").Value
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub`

Comment: Hmm... Are you sure that you provided the correct code? This code only modifies LeftHeader and RightHeader - not CenterHeader as you mention.

Comment: Yes I know there is no CenterHeader. But it always does the same.  No matter how i write.. I wanted to fill only left and right at the moment, because i don't know what will be in centerHeader yet..